# JOIN three tables not quite producing results needed

Tags: mysql

I have tried for a number of hours to get this. I am still quite new to mysql but have managed to achieve queries that I was impressed with after using the resources and examples I found. I am a bit stuck here. Apologies if I do not ask this very well.

Three tables that are used for managing categories and category membership within a project.

```
table a = project membership
id user_id project_id
== ======= ==========
1  1       10
2  1       12
3  3       45
4  5       12



table b = categories 
id name project_id
== ==== ==========
1  cat1 10
2  cat4 12
3  cat8 45




tabke c = category members
id user_id_added category_id capability
== ============= =========== ==========
1  1             2           1
2  3             3           2
3  5             3           1
4  5             2           0



Required result


members of project 2

user_id category capability_in_category
======= ======== ====================== 
1       2        1
5       2        0


SELECT a.user_id
       , c.capability
       , b.id as category

    FROM a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN b
           ON a.project_id = c.project_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN c
           ON b.id = c.category_id
       WHERE a.project_id = $project_id
       AND c.category_id = $category_id;
```

It feels like I don't need to join the three tables, but I do not see a way of joining the project table with the category membership table without using the category table (b). The query I am running nearly works, but user capability is not returning correct. I am using left outer joins as a member may not always be part of a category, but they still need to be shown as a member in the project.  I have been trying various joins and subqueries, without success. I basically need a list of the members in the project and if they are part of a category, to show the capability they have of the specific category. I feel there are a few ways of doing this potentially, but there is a gray area I am struggling to bridge.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is vague so I might help you to solve the wrong problem but if you want to have all members of a specific project listed (regardless of their capability) and to list the capabilities in a specified category listed as well, then:

```
SELECT project_memberships.user_id
   , category_members.category_id AS category
   , category_members.capability AS capability

FROM project_members
   LEFT OUTER JOIN categories
       ON project_members.project_id = categories.project_id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN category_members
       ON categories.id = category_members.category_id
       AND category_members.user_id_added = project_membership.user_id
   WHERE project_members.project_id = $project_id
   AND (categories.id = $category_id OR categories.id IS NULL);
```

should get you that.

I altered tree things compared to your original query:

1. I used the table names as they are more speaking than "a, b, c"
2. I added the additional constraint `category_members.user_id_added = project_membership.user_id` to the second join so as to not join category_members of a different user to a project_members record.
3. I loosened the `WHERE` condition so that members not having the desired capability are also displayed. `category` and `capability` will be `NULL` for those records.

As to your question regarding having to join the three tables the answer is yes, you need to do that.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that I need to go through all three. It is an interesting option at the end. I have been staring at this a long time and become more confused as I have gone along, I will rest and see if I can explain myself better. Thanks

Comment: I think the problem I have in my result is that eg: two users in the project, one user is part of a category, but the result is giving me the capability in the category for both project users. It should be returning null for the second user, but I think the join is still working as there is nothing to clarify that the join with the third table should give no return results for the second user. I instead get the capability of the first user as the capbility of the second user

Comment: incredible. I was starting to create some really complicated structures to try and achieve this. I never really have understood you could add an additional constraint in a join. I think you have opened up my mysql world up a little further. Many thanks, I can breath again.

Comment: Been a pleasure helping you out.